# WebRequest within Soap

Tags: c#, soap

I am hoping someone will be able to help me, I haven't been programming in C# for a while. I'm sure the answer will be simple but i just can't get my head around it.

I have the following, where i call System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol. I have included just one of the many calls that i have.

```
public partial class ExchangeService : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol   {

//Lots of code using Soap 

    [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("getDetailsLite", RequestNamespace="http://www.MySite.com/ExchangeService/", ResponseNamespace=" http://www.MySite.com/ExchangeService/", ", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
    [return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Result", IsNullable=true)]
    public GetDetailsLiteResp getDetailsLite(getDetailsLiteReq request) {
        object[] results = this.Invoke("getDetailsLite", new object[] {
                    request});
        return ((getDetailsLiteResp)(results[0]));
    }

    public void getDetailsLiteAsync(getDetailsLiteReq request) {
        this. getDetailsLiteAsync(request, null);
    }

    public void getDetailsLiteAsync (getDetailsLiteReq request, object userState) {
        if ((this.getDetailsLiteOperationCompleted == null)) {
            this.getDetailsLiteOperationCompleted = new System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback(this.OngetDetailsLiteOperationCompleted);
        }
        this.InvokeAsync("getDetailsLite", new object[] {
                    request}, this. getDetailsLiteOperationCompleted, userState);
    }
}
```

I want to override the WebRequest that the SoapHttpClientProtocol calls. 
The SoapHttpClientProtocol looks like this (which I believe is called from System.Web.Services.dll)

```
namespace System.Web.Services.Protocols  {
    public class SoapHttpClientProtocol : HttpWebClientProtocol    {
    public SoapHttpClientProtocol();
    public SoapProtocolVersion SoapVersion { get; set; }
    protected IAsyncResult BeginInvoke(string methodName, object[] parameters, AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState);
    public void Discover();
    protected object[] EndInvoke(IAsyncResult asyncResult);
    protected virtual XmlReader GetReaderForMessage(SoapClientMessage message, int bufferSize);

    //This line is the one i am talking about
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri);

    protected virtual XmlWriter GetWriterForMessage(SoapClientMessage message, int bufferSize);
    protected object[] Invoke(string methodName, object[] parameters);
    protected void InvokeAsync(string methodName, object[] parameters, SendOrPostCallback callback);
    protected void InvokeAsync(string methodName, object[] parameters, SendOrPostCallback callback, object userState);
    }
}
```

I need protected the override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri ) to look like this:

```
protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)  {
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest) base.GetWebRequest(uri);
    webRequest.KeepAlive = false;
    webRequest.ProtocolVersion=HttpVersion.Version10;
    return webRequest;
}
```

Does anyone know how i would do this? I am uanble to edit it directly inside of the SoapHttpClientProtocol which im 99% sure i shouldn't be doing anyway.

Thanks for any help you may be able to provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclass it? *GetWebRequest* is [marked as virtual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.webclientprotocol.getwebrequest.aspx) in the root class *WebClientProtocol*, so you can override the method.

```
public class MyHttpProtocol : SoapHttpClientProtocol  
{
    public override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
    {
        // Base request:
        WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(uri);

        // You code goes here...

        // Return...
        return request;
    }
}
```

Then use *MyHttpProtocol* as needed within your service class.

Comment: OK, got the following error (cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'protected' inherited member) so i had to change it to

    public new WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
    {
      // my code
    }

Answer (score 2):

Since `ExchangeService` is a [partial class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx), you can create another file that adds to the declaration of `ExchangeService` and also declares a suitable override for GetWebRequest.  This will allow you to write custom functionality for `ExchangeService`, while still having it be updatable if the WSDL changes.

For more info, see the MSDN article [Partial Classes and Methods (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx).