# How to convert a SoapHttpClientProtocol to HTTPS

Tags: c#, web-services, https

Can I convert a SoapHttpClientProtocol class, created from a WSDL automatically to use the HTTPS protocol instead of HTTP? (and if, how?)

Simply changing the URL access of the webservice from `http://` to `https://` results in an exception:

> The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format

My problem is, that the class is very large (think 10k SLOCs) and I'm not really sure how I need to go about changing protocols here.

Comment: This is not an answer, so I put it into a comment. Florian, normally what you did is enough, i.e. you just change the url and the `SoapHttpClientProtocol` supports SSL out of the box. The exception you get is probably due to some other issues, not related to `SoapHttpClientProtocol`. I suggest googling this particular exception and trying to find what scenarios people report as the source of the exception. My guess would be an incompatible proxy at the client machine but, of course, other causes are also probable.

Comment: I did that - most of the issues I was able to find dealt with direct connections however. Meaning that the code opened the connection himself, which is why those are not applicable to my case I think - I don't open any connection, as this is all handled by the SOAP class (AFAIK?)

Comment: If I remember correctly, the `SoapHttpClientProtocol` has the `Proxy` property you could possibly try to set to point to a proxy that uses (or doesn't use) the local proxy. However, if the problem is at the server side then doing anything on client won't help.

Comment: Use MS Network Monitor or similar to check WSDL format of the reply, figure out which format you are using at the client (for SSL Authentication), do they match / are compatible? Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007371/webrequest-within-soap for info on changing the protocol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can figure from searching the new, you should be able to do it by adding the lines

```
this.Url = "https://example.com:443/servlet_path";
this.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

to the constructor of your derived `SoapHttpClientProtocol` class and

```
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute(
  "http://example.com/servlet_path",
  RequestNamespace="http://example.com/",
  ResponseNamespace="http://example.com/",
  Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal,
  ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
```

to the definition of your functions. In one page they mentioned that you might need to override the default certificate validator if the target machine does not have a certificate from a CA the executing machine accepts.